# Cron expression to run job once on application sturtup

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I'm using `org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean` for trigger job.

Could you propose **cron expression** to trigger job execution **only once on application startup** pls?

Comment: Hm, why using a scheduler if the job is going to be triggered only once?

Comment: I have different environments my application to be deployed to. On dev environment I want to run job only once and I want to change my configuration file accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the actual answer is: no, you can't. 
What you could do however when using Spring 3.1 (which is Milestone 2 at the time of writing) is create [profiles](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/) which can be enabled for different environments. So you can use different beans and bean configurations depending on profiles you enable.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using scheduling, I would prefer to invoke your trigger via defining an `init-method` in your spring configuration

Answer (score 1):

To run a job only once at startup with the Spring Quartz scheduler you can use the `org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean` which doesn't take a cronExpression but a `startDelay` and a `repeatCount`. Set the `repeatCount` to `0` for a single execution (see Quartz documentation on SimpleTrigger for further options).

```
<bean id="doJobOnceOnStartupTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="myJobDetail" />
    <property name="startDelay" value="5000" />
    <property name="repeatCount" value="0" />   
</bean>

<bean id="myJobDetail" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="myBean" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="myMethod" />
</bean>
```

Additional information can be found int the 
[spring documentation: Chapter 22. Scheduling jobs using Quartz or Timer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.2.5/reference/scheduling.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`SimpleTriggerBean`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/SimpleTriggerBean.html) - with a cron expression, you won't achieve this